# ASP.NET 5 and Sitecore 8

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I've created a new project in Visual Studio 2015 with ASP.NET 5. I've created a web application, now I want to add Sitecore to the project but I'm not able to find any documentation on this.

So my question is where I can find a guide how to implement Sitecore 8 and C#? Is this even possible?

Comment: For supported .NET version see the Sitecore Compatibility Table https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164  today .NET 5 is not on the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**. My fault I understood your question incorrectly :)

As far as I know Sitecore doesn't support ASP.NET 5.0 yet. I checked the ASP.NET 5 road map (ASP.NET Core 1.0 is the new name) and it looks like the first version will be this year (https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap). So I suggest to not use Sitecore with ASP.NET 5 until Sitecore will officially support it.

Some other guys asked same question on community: 
    https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/440

https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/t/736

I also added Sitecore Compatibility Table

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164 from the comments.

Comment: I think this solution is a bit out-dated :P since I want to try the asp.net 5.0 where you don't have web.config and no app_config. This is how a solution looks like: http://prntscr.com/9yghom. i've created an empty solution also and it looks like: http://prntscr.com/9ygimt so no web config the new solution for visual studio 2015 looks a bit diffrent

Comment: Well ASP.NET Core 1.0 is not only entirely new framework but also not released yet. It is a bit early to expect support from third party CMS

Comment: Worth adding this in: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164 to your answer. Covers what .net frameworks are supported and more.

Comment: Sitecore is going to have to rewrite a ton of code to make 5.0 work. I can't wait because I love the idea of Sitecore on a inexpensive Linux box in AWS. But I think we are a few years out as Sitecore has a lot in their roadmap right now.